# Android: Disable Buttons on Screen-Tap

Tags: android, android-viewpager, listener, gesture

I want to disable my shown buttons when a user performs a single-tap on the screen. I currently have a ViewPager on my MainActivity and the mentioned buttons.

Which Listener do I have to use in order to fetch the single-tap event and where do I have to "put" it on, so it does not override my swipe-gesture from my viewPager? (I tried to put an onTouchListener on my viewPager which did work, but I could not swipe anymore, obviously)

My code for illustration (please be gentle, I am totally new to Android :) ):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GestureDetector.OnGestureListener{ 
(some Code, onCreate etc...)
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        int action = MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event);

        switch(action) {
            case (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) :
                Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Action was DOWN");
                return true;
            case (MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) :
                Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Action was MOVE");
                return true;
            case (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) :
                triggerButtons();
                Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Action was UP");
                return true;
            case (MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) :
                Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Action was CANCEL");
                return true;
            case (MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE) :
                Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Movement occurred outside bounds " +
                        "of current screen element");
                return true;
            default :
                return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
}

@Override
public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {

}

@Override
public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
    triggerButtons();
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {

}

@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
    return false;
}
```

So as you can see, I want my "triggerButtons" to be fired, when the user lifts his finger after a touch/tap happened. What listener do I need to assign in my onCreate to make this work?

(if you also know how I can listen to a doubleTap, that would be so great!)

Edit:

I have added

```
View.OnTouchListener mOnTouchListener; 
GestureDetector mGestureDetector;
```

This I added to my onCreate in my MainActivity:

```
mOnTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() { 
    @Override public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {  
    mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event); 
    return false; 
   } 
};
```

and

```
mViewPager.setOnTouchListener(mOnTouchListener);
```

---

Solution:

In onCreate:

```
mOnTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            touchEventDecider(event);
            return false;
        }
    };
```

Method touchEventDecider:

```
private boolean touchEventDecider(MotionEvent event) {
    int action = MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event);

    switch(action) {
        case (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) :
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Action was DOWN");
            return true;
        case (MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) :
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Action was MOVE");
            return true;
        case (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) :
            triggerButtons();
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Action was UP");
            return true;
        case (MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) :
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Action was CANCEL");
            return true;
        case (MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE) :
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Movement occurred outside bounds " +
                    "of current screen element");
            return true;
        default :
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `OnTouchListener` to your `ViewPager`. In `onTouchEvent` method of your `TouchListener` pass each event to your `GestureDetector` and return `false`. In `GestureDetector` return `true` in `onDown` and leave only `onSingleTapUp` as you have it.

Your problem is that you consume every touch event in your `onTouchEvent` method by returning `true` thus events are not coming to your `ViewPager` making it unscrollable.

**EDIT:** If you want to recognize single tap by yourself without using `GestureDetector` then just attach `OnTouchListener` to your `ViewPager` as you did but don't forget to return `false` there in `onTouchEvent` method.

Comment: I have added 
View.OnTouchListener mOnTouchListener;
GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

This I added to my onCreate in my MainActivity:
mOnTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                return false;
            }
        };

and
mViewPager.setOnTouchListener(mOnTouchListener);

It's still not working, most likely I am doing something wrong. Thanks for the answer so far!

Comment: @Vancore Looks like second option helped you. Unfortunatly I can't check why approach with GestureDetector is not working. Perhaps I made a mistake in return value at some point.